# How to pad Background size in Style calls

Tags: graphics

When highlighting text using `Style` and `Background`, as in `Style["Test   ", White, Background -> Lighter@Blue]` is there a way to pad (ie, enlarge) the bounding box?

The bottom of the background seems coincident with the base of the text: [image: here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Style[Pane[" Test "], White, Background -> Lighter@Blue]
```

> [image]

**Edit**

Controlling the padding:

```
Style[Pane[" Test ", ImageMargins -> 10], White,  Background -> Lighter@Blue]
```

Comment: Ok that works. But is there no way to parametrically control size? (Other than rendering an independent Rectangle)

Comment: @alancalvitti Add that request to the question. I tried to answer it in its current state

Comment: @alancalvitti See edit

Answer (score 3):

You could play with the `FrameMargins` ...

```
Framed[Style["Test", White], FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 2, 
 Background -> Lighter@Blue]
```

[image: test]