# Visualizing the difference between two sequences (strings)

Tags: string-manipulation, visualization

I'm trying to develop a way of comparing two sequences (probably originally text, such as text writing or source code, possibly converted to lists). As a familiar example, consider the revisions display for [any typical SE question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/11880/revisions) or the [diff](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/DIFF/) output from a command-line `diff`.

I found a cool *Mathematica* function called `SequenceAlignment` which looks promising:

```
text1 = ExampleData[{"Text", "ToBeOrNotToBe"}];
text2 = StringReplace[text1, {"s" -> "th"}]

(* 
To be, or not to be,--that ith the quethtion:-- Whether 'tith nobler
in the mind to thuffer The thlingth and arrowth of outrageouth 
fortune Or to take armth againtht a thea of troubleth, And by 
oppothing end them? ...
*)
```

(lisp programming... :)

Now:

```
sa = SequenceAlignment[text1, text2]
```

gives:

```
{"To be, or not to be,--that i", {"s", "th"}, " the que", {"s", "th"}, 
"tion:-- Whether 'ti", {"s", "th"}, " nobler in the mind to ", {"s", "th"},
"uffer " ...
```

which I want to convert to some kind of colored display. The best I've managed so far is this:

```
 Reap[
  If[Length[#] == 2,  
     Sow[Column[{Style[#[[1]], Red], Style[#[[2]], Green]}]],  
     Sow[Style[#, Black]]]
     & /@
  sa]
```

but it's not a pretty display:

[image: my attempt]

How can I make this display look like a single piece of text with colored markup, like the SE revisions display? And would it be possible to process *Mathematica* code as well - without evaluating said code first, obviously?

Comment: A nice question for a graphical designer. A best fit for this site could be: "I want the output like **this**. How to do it in Mma?"

Comment: @belisarius I've focussed the question a bit more. I don't know how to get from the information in `sa` to a text display. And I don't know whether `SequenceAlignment` is the right tool for the job...

Comment: Ok, +1 then. Nice question

Comment: Your approach might encounter a problem in some cases, try to use `text2 = StringReplace[text1, {"s" -> "ss"}]` and see how your output looks like.

Comment: @VLC yes, it's not good so far :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's a start (perhaps it's better to say *continuation* since you've already gotten started):

```
Row@Flatten[sa /. {a_, b_} :> { Style[a, Red], "(", Style[b, Green], ")"}]
```

[image: syntax]

By capturing the word fragmentth to the left and right of `a`, you thhould be able to end up with thomething more like:

[image]

Comment: Yeth, that's exthellent!

Answer (score 46):

The undocumented `` System`Dump`showStringDiff `` function neatly does the diff and highlights it for you. The simplest usage is:

```
System`Dump`showStringDiff[text1, text2]
```

[image: diff]

You can choose custom colours for the highlights with the `Styles` option. You can also change the background, font weight, add a strikethrough, etc.:

```
System`Dump`showStringDiff[text1, text2, Styles -> {
    {Bold, Background -> LightGreen, Darker@Green}, 
    {FontVariations -> {"StrikeThrough" -> True}, Background -> LightRed, Darker@Red}
}]
```

[image: styled diff]

A related undocumented function `` System`Dump`showStringDiffs `` takes the same arguments and options, but returns a list of two strings with the deletions marked in one and the additions in the other.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How did you find this?! +1

Comment: More great hidden functionality!  The problem is this has the same problem with wrapping across lines that most of the methods have

Comment: What are you doing on your free time? ... no, wait, don't answer.

Comment: Good find - a pretty cool option hidden away. I wonder why it's been included at all if no-one knows about it...

Answer (score 16):

Using [How to join two Style[]d strings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10990/how-to-join-two-styled-strings), we can get a decent looking display on the the test case

```
Flatten[Map[If[Length[#] == 2, {Style[#[[1]], Red, FontVariations -> {"StrikeThrough" -> True}], Style[#[[2]], Green]}, #] &, sa]];
Apply[StringJoin, ToString[#, StandardForm] & /@ %]
```

[image]

Note that with this method text correctly wraps across lines

**Update**

Using background to do the highlighting doesn't work well since you can't control the background size the default way.  [How to pad Background size in Style calls](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8567/how-to-pad-background-size-in-style-calls) is an attempt to do text highlighting, but doesn't work well in this case because of text wrapping issues:

```
Flatten[Map[
     If[Length[#] == 2, 
          {Framed[Style[#[[1]], FontVariations -> {"StrikeThrough" -> True}],FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 2, Background -> Lighter@Red], 
          Framed[#[[2]], FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 2, Background -> Lighter@Green]}, 
          Framed[#, FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 2]] &, sa]];
Apply[StringJoin, ToString[#, StandardForm] & /@ %]
```

[image]

Comment: Like it. Good attempt on background colouring too.