# Why does MapIndexed return the index in a list?

Tags: functions, design-patterns

`MapIndex` returns the index in a list instead of as shown in my revised example.  I can work with it (or work around it), but what's the design concept?  It seems like an unnecessary complication, but I'm sure there is a reason I don't see.

[image]

I tagged this with a design-pattern tag.  I'm not sure if that's appropriate. Editors please remove the tag if it's not.

Comment: I guess this is due to the fact that once you provide a levelspec, it becomes necessary, consider: `MapIndexed[f, {{a, b}, {c, d, e}}, {2}]`

Comment: In addition to what others said, one can remove this {} using First@ like this:  `MapIndexed[f[#1, First@#2] &, {a, b, c, d}]` gives `{f[a, 1], f[b, 2], f[c, 3], f[d, 4]}`

Comment: @PinguinDirk I just looked at your example and see how it works.  Level specifications are tricky: e.g. 2 vs {2}. I know how it works, but I try to stay on deck one.

Comment: Today's interest in expression diffs reminded me about my [expression diff code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24418/comparing-mathematica-expressions-like-diff/24463#24463), where there is an application of `MapIndexed` mapping on possibly deeply nested expression - there I used the second argument essentially as a unique Id for a part in an expression.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "unnecessary" complication is needed for those cases where you specify deeper levels than the first:

```
MapIndexed[f, {{a}, {b}}, {2}]
(* {{f[a, {1, 1}]}, {f[b, {2, 1}]}} *)
```

The following code produces what you want:

```
myMapIndexed[f_, l_] := Inner[f, l, Range[Length[l]], List];
myMapIndexed[f, {a, b, c, d}]
(* {f[a, 1], f[b, 2], f[c, 3], f[d, 4]} *)
```

Comment: I get it.  I haven't had an application with a nested structure come up in anything I've done.  Thanks.