# Visually identifying differences between two Mathematica functions

Tags: front-end, debugging, interactive

**Context**

Let us assume we have two functions defined in Mathematica.
I am interested in spotting the differences in the code for the two functions.

**Example**

```
  f[x_,y_]:= Module[{t}, t= x+y; Sin[t]];
  g[x_,y_]:= Module[{t}, t= x-y; Sin[t]];
```

> I would like to be able to select both codes and have the front end produce a highlight of the differences in colour.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is something that word editors do routinely.

**Attempt**

I don't know anything about  front-end coding.
This 3 solutions might be a good starting point (inline not with the FE)?

1/ Following [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13312/1089)

```
st1 = Definition[f] // ToString
st2 = Definition[g] // ToString
sa = SequenceAlignment[st1, st2];
 Row@
 Flatten[sa /. {a_, b_} :> {Style[a, Red], "(", Style[b, Green], ")"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

2/  or using  `showStringDiff`

```
System`Dump`showStringDiff[ToString@Definition[f],ToString@Definition[g]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

3/ Finally [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24463/1089) other code by LeonidShifrin

```
  visualExprDiff[str1, str2]
```

yields

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If one assigns

```
str1 = "Hold[" <> ToString[Definition[f]] <> "]" // ToExpression
str2 = "Hold[" <> ToString[Definition[g]] <> "]" // ToExpression
```

**Update**

FIY the `showStringDiff` above (though not interactive) did the job for me and produced the difference I needed to spot my bug.

PS: *One thing this would require is selecting two functions which might not be next to each other in the notebook (though this can be avoided by duplicating the code I guess).*

Comment: Have you seen [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24418/comparing-mathematica-expressions-like-diff)?

Comment: It should be doable, but not a one-liner. You would have to compare `DownValues`, `OwnValues`, possibly also `SubValues` and `UpValues`. Further, each function can have multiple definitions / rules defined for it,  and they may have somewhat different ordering for the two functions. So one would have to somehow first preprocess the definitions and extract which pieces to compare to which, if one wants to get a better / more meaningful comparison. This isn't impossible, but would take some work to implement.

Comment: Yeah, you could use that code, I guess, although there surely exists a way to avoid `ToString` - `ToExpression` stage. As to the answers, I have no strong opinion, but I'd probably leave things as they are now, at least for some time.