# Combine a pure function, a replacement rule and Map

Tags: functions

I've imported an Excel with 2 columns (Address and Final Address) which are both urls.

```
myimport = {{"Address", 
  "Final Address"}, 
{"http://saliscale.it/news/10-consigli-di-esperti-serramentisti-per-
aiutarti-a-scegliere-gli-infissi/", 
  "https://saliscale.it/news/10-consigli-di-esperti-serramentisti-per-
aiutarti-a-scegliere-gli-infissi/"}, {"http://www.anekitalia.com/", 
  "https://www.anekitalia.com/"}, {"http://www.bagnochic.com/", 
  "https://www.bagnochic.com/"}}
```

Then I defined a pure function to match a List of 2 elements and Mapped it to all the elements of the list:

```
f[{a_, b_}] :=  SequenceAlignment[a, b]
Map[f, myimport[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]
```

Reading [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13315/13321) I wanted to Apply to each element of the list a second function:

```
Row[Flatten[
  sa /. {a_, b_} :> {Style[a, Red], "(", Style[b, Green], ")"}]]
```

sa is defined in the question that I've linked and it's just

```
sa = SequenceAlignment[text1, text2]
```

How can I combine f and the replacement copied from the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f[{a_, b_}] := SequenceAlignment[a, b]

sa = Map[f, myimport[[All, 1 ;; 2]]];

Row[Flatten[sa /. {a_String, b_String} :>
    {Style[a, Red], "(", Style[b, Green], ")"}]]
```

Specifying the type (String) for `a` and/or `b` prevents the replacement applying to the overall lists.

Alternatively, with output as strings:

```
f[{a_, b_}] := StringJoin[SequenceAlignment[a, b] /. 
   {c_String, d_String} :>
    {ToString[Style[c, Red], StandardForm], "(",
     ToString[Style[d, Green], StandardForm], ")"}]

Column[Map[f, myimport[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]]
```